# Replace NULL by NA in a column using awk

Tags: unix, awk, replace

I have a file: allele_freq.vcf.
These are the first 10 rows in the file

```
NC_000001.9   144148243  rs2236566     G  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2806   236
NC_000001.9   146267105  rs1553119693  T  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  33978  26317
NC_000001.10  13832431   rs1553119928  T  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0
NC_000001.10  74439690   rs1553119957  A  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0
NC_000001.11  10498      rs1338146081  G  A,T  .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      0
NC_000001.11  10509      rs1262211809  G  A    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0
NC_000001.11  10527      rs1246002416  C  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0
NC_000001.11  10531      rs1293328578  C  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0
```

For column 12 I would like to replace empty cells with NA

I have tried

```
awk -F='' '$12== "" {$12="NA"; print; next} {print}' OFS='' allele_freq.vcf
```

Which gives me this

```
NC_000001.9   144148243  rs2236566     G  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2806   236    NA
NC_000001.9   146267105  rs1553119693  T  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  33978  26317  NA
NC_000001.10  13832431   rs1553119928  T  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0      NA
NC_000001.10  74439690   rs1553119957  A  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10498      rs1338146081  G  A,T  .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      0NA
NC_000001.11  10509      rs1262211809  G  A    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10527      rs1246002416  C  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10531      rs1293328578  C  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10534      rs1486704209  A  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10535      rs1184627952  G  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
```

The 0 in row 5 has an "NA" attached to it.

What I want is something like this:

```
NC_000001.9   144148243  rs2236566     G  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2806   236    NA
NC_000001.9   146267105  rs1553119693  T  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  33978  26317  NA
NC_000001.10  13832431   rs1553119928  T  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0      NA
NC_000001.10  74439690   rs1553119957  A  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10498      rs1338146081  G  A,T  .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      0
NC_000001.11  10509      rs1262211809  G  A    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10527      rs1246002416  C  T    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10531      rs1293328578  C  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10534      rs1486704209  A  G    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10535      rs1184627952  G  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0 (NF<12 ? OFS "NA" : "")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, except for the amount of space before `NA`. Adjust as needed:

```
awk '{if (NF<12) print $0 " NA"; else print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of your code and the structure of fixed width format, there is space after the `$11` even when the `$12` is empty. Therefore:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ +$/,"&NA")}1' file
```

Partial output:

```
...
NC_000001.10  74439690   rs1553119957  A  C    .  .  .  AN:AC  1220   0      NA
NC_000001.11  10498      rs1338146081  G  A,T  .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      0
NC_000001.11  10509      rs1262211809  G  A    .  .  .  AN:AC  2072   0      NA
...
```